# List of 3D points to 3d map in XNA 4.0

Tags: c#, xna

how to transform a list of 3D points to a smooth plane based on the 3D points provided?

basically, I have this formula and the goal image [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImpGC.png)
and I was able to put it on XNA. However, mine looks like shit [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUKup.png), please give me some advice. Thank you.
Here is part of the code:

```
private void pointPositionCalculation()
    {
        for (int x = -(nrofPointsX / 2); x < nrofPointsX/2 ; x++) 
        {
            for (int z =-(nrofPointsZ / 2); z < nrofPointsZ/2; z++)
            {
                // the given equation for surface. 
                float y = (float)(0.3f * Math.Sin(3 * Math.Sqrt((x - 5)*(x -5) + (z - 5)*(z-5)) + 0.5f * Math.Cos(x + z)));

                originalSurface.Add(new Vector3(x, y, z));

            }
        }


        //Find the max Y value
        float maxY = originalSurface[0].Y;
        for (int i = 0; i < originalSurface.Count; i++)
        {
            if (originalSurface[i].Y > maxY) maxY = originalSurface[i].Y;
        }
        //Find the min Y value
        float minY = originalSurface[0].Y;
        for (int i = 0; i < originalSurface.Count; i++)
        {
            if (originalSurface[i].Y < minY) minY = originalSurface[i].Y;
        }


        //Change the range of surface
        float oldRange = maxY - minY;
        float newRange = 2.0f; //Defined new Range
        for (int i = 0; i < nrofPointsX*nrofPointsZ; i++)
        {
            float newValueY = (((originalSurface[i].Y - minY) * newRange) / oldRange);
            surface.Add(new Vector3(originalSurface[i].X, newValueY, originalSurface[i].Z));
        }
    }
```

Besides, can you tell me how to achieve a smooth plane from these points?

Comment: The calculation in the image is missing a closing bracket for the `SIN` function. You placed that bracket at the end (after the `COS`), are you sure that formular is correct that way? I would actually expect it to be like `float y = (float)(0.3f * Math.Sin(3 * Math.Sqrt((x - 5)*(x -5) + (z - 5)*(z-5))) + 0.5f * Math.Cos(x + z));`

Comment: Indeed, thanks. my mistake.

Comment: Did that fix your problem? If so I would post it as an answer, so it can be accepted.